# Display only one validation error message

Tags: laravel, octobercms

There is a validation rule for a model:

```
 $rules = [
     'uid' => 'required|digits_between:3,9|numeric'
 ];

 $messages = [
     'uid.digits_between' => 'Length between 3 and 9',
     'uid.numeric' => 'Only numbers',
     '*.required' => 'The field is required'
 ];
```

If I type a character in `uid` input 2 messages will display - `Length between 3 and 9` and `Only numbers`.

How to display only one message in this situation - `Only numbers`, but keep `digits_between` rule working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `bail` rule? (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic - Stopping On First Validation Failure)

```
$rules = [
     'uid' => 'bail|required|digits_between:3,9|numeric'
];
```

Comment: Thank you! There's no information about `bail` in October docs =)